# Connecting to FPGA through MATLAB

Tags: matlab, xilinx-ise

I am working on a project that requires me to use the system generator option on MATLAB. I connect the Spartan-6 board and generate the Jtag Cosim model. After finishing all of that, I try to run the program and I get an error which states:

> Error opening programming cable.

os: WIndows 7.
MATLAB 2010b.
Xilinx 13.1.
fpga : Spartan 6.

Comment: What development board are you using?  If it's Xilinx, they have a USB cable to connect the JTAG port.  Although I haven't used the Spartan 6 Xilinx dev board, I have used the Virtex 7 board, which required 3rd party software to be installed to allow programming of the FPGA via USB.  I think it was Diligent.

Comment: I'm using the XC6SLX4 , I'm using the USB cable itself and Digilent itself.

Comment: Try using Chipscope Analyzer 13.1 and click the button "Open Cable/Search JTAG chain".  If that doesn't work, then there's a problem with the drivers.